# Python InlineKeyboardButton

Tags: python, telebot

Метод класса:

```
def default_test(self,last_chat_id):
  method = 'sendMessage'
  #message = "Привет! Нажми на кнопку и перейди в поисковик."
  keyboard = types.InlineKeyboardButton('Option 1')
  reply_markup = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup()
  reply_markup.add(keyboard)
  params = {'chat_id': last_chat_id, 'reply_markup': reply_markup}
  response =requests.post(self.api_url + method, params)
  return response
```

Вызов метода:

```
if last_chat_text.lower() == 'тест':
    greet_bot.default_test(last_chat_id)
```

Ничего не происходит. Должна появляться кнопка. Подскажите, что не так?

Answer (score 0):

```
import telebot as tb

bot = tb('<token>')


@bot.message_handler(regexp='тест')
def handle_text(message):
    return default_test(message.chat.id)


def default_test(chat_id):
    reply_markup = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup()
    button = types.InlineKeyboardButton('Option 1')
    reply_markup.add(button)
    return bot.send_message(chat_id, text='hello', reply_markup=reply_markup)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    bot.polling()
```

Но не знаю зачем вы разделили функции.